# Composer update installed.json - autoloading not working

Tags: composer-php, autoload

I was using Composer to install a package. After the dependencies, the final install failed because the docker container couldn't complete the process. Instead, I had to download the zip from github and unpack it manually.
I have run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Hoping it would pick up the new files. But, the namespaces associated with that package aren't working (whereas they ARE working for the dependencies).
Looking in the `vendor/installed.json` I don't see any reference to that package. Nor in composer.lock in the project root.

Is this reason why the autoloader and/or namespacing isn't working? If so, how do I fix it? (I don't want to run install again on that package because it takes forever and then breaks)

Note: when unzipped, that package is 73MB and 29,000 files!

Comment: "the final install failed" - why not share the error message, along with your attempts to resolve the problem? Manually unpacking stuff in the vendor folder does not sound like a good idea to me

Comment: @NicoHaase when I say it failed, there were no error messages. Originally it was timing out so I kept upping the "process-timeout" in the composer config. I was running it in a docker container as well, on my local machine. In the end, in the time it took me to download the zip from Github, and unzip it on the desktop and copy it across to the working folder (which was probably approaching an hour), the composer process was still going. So I terminated it. This was about the 6th time I'd given up on it.

Comment: I don't have an answer to my original question but I got it working by manually adding the src folder of the downloaded files to the autoload section of the composer config. Then I ran the "composer dump-autoload" at that point, and it got my namespaces working - all new classmaps, autoload files etc. What would be good is if there was a different way of rewriting the installed.json without having to manually add it, but I guess there's a reason for that file being what it is. Lucky for me there is only one src directory to add.

Comment: Please add all the important details to your question by [edit]ing it. Also please provide the output of `composer diagnose` by adding it to your question. You can obtain more details to see where composer install hangs by increasing its verbosity with the `-v` / `-vv` or `-vvv`  global switches (verbose, more verbose, debug).